# Ensure a user can only SSH to the port they have been designated

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

**CentOS 6**

I want port 22 to be used for normal SSH access and for port 8822 to be used for jailed SFTP.

Here's my sshd_config configuration

```
Port 22
Port 8822
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
AllowUsers user1 test_sftp

Match User user1 LocalPort 22
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User test_sftp LocalPort 8822
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        PubkeyAuthentication no
```

The configuration above does not work. Both users have SSH access for both ports.

This does not work either. I get `Starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 143: Directive 'AllowUsers' is not allowed within a Match block`

```
Match LocalPort 22
    AllowUsers user1

Match LocalPort 8822
    AllowUsers test_sftp
```

I have manage to prevent *test_sftp* user from shell access as well as logging in to the physical server through `chsh -s /bin/false`. However, they still can connect via SFTP into port 22 which is not jailed.

**CentOS 7+**

Here's what I am trying to achieve on CentOS 6. The following works on CentOS 7 and above.

```
Port 22
Port 8822

PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

# Normal SSH and SFTP users
Match User nagios
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User user1
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication no

Match Address 192.168.1.0/22 LocalPort 22
        AllowUsers user1

Match Address 203.12.63.32/27 LocalPort 22
        AllowUsers nagios user1 

# Jailed SFTP users
Match User test_sftp
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match Address 101.168.167.33 LocalPort 8822
        AllowUsers test_sftp

Match LocalPort 8822
    ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect example of the XY Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  
What underlying issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want port 22 to be for normal SSH and port 8822 for jailed SFTP. I know CentOS 6 is end-of-life already but it something I need to work with for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend designating a port for a user. A port is mapped to a service. Usually a user is mapped to a home directory and a group which is attached to a ACL, to ensure the user has permissions on the required folders. For extra security you can use public key authentication for a user on SSH, so the user has to generate a public and private key to able to connect.

And you can't run a service like SSH on two ports.

If the user comes in from the same IP and location all the time, you can set up a list in iptables or another firewall to allow the ip's where the user s connect from, but that's also not the ideal solution (that can be faked by threat actors).

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, since the test_sftp user is on a different IPs, I can have separate NAT rules on the firewall. I have set the two rules as follows:

- Source IP: 203.12.63.32/27, external port: 22, internal IP: 192.168.1.20, port: 22
- Source IP: 101.168.167.33/32, external port: 8822, internal IP: 192.168.1.20, port: 8822

This will work in this case but if for some reason the IP happened to be the same, it will not work.

Here's a script for adding a new SFTP user which cannot SSH or login into the physical server.

```
PASSWD=''
USERNAME='test_sftp'

useradd $USERNAME
echo $PASSWD | passwd test_sftp --stdin
chsh -s /bin/false $USERNAME
mkdir /home/$USERNAME/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/$USERNAME/.ssh
touch /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /home/$USERNAME/.ssh

mkdir -p /home/sftp/$USERNAME/uploads
mkdir -p /home/sftp/$USERNAME/downloads
chown root:root /home/sftp
chown root:root /home/sftp/$USERNAME
chown $USERNAME:$USERNAME /home/sftp/$USERNAME/uploads
chown $USERNAME:$USERNAME /home/sftp/$USERNAME/downloads
```

Modify the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file as follows:

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Port 22
Port 8822

PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

AllowUsers nagios user1 test_sftp

# Normal SSH and SFTP users
Match User nagios
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match User user1
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication no

# Jailed SFTP users
Match User test_sftp
    PasswordAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match LocalPort 8822
    ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```